# sqlite3 sqlite3_prepare_v2 segment fault

Tags: c, sqlite

In the test program:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     main(void) 
{
   sqlite3        *conn;
   sqlite3_stmt   *res;
   int            rc          =   0;
   int            rec_count   =   0;
   const char     *errMSG;
   const char     *tail;
   const char     *sql;

   rc = sqlite3_open("ljdata.sl3", &conn);
   if (rc) 
   {   puts("Can not open database");
      exit(0);
   }
   printf ("database open\n");

   sql   =   "create table if not exists people (id int, firstname varchar(20), lastname varchar(20), phonenumber char(10))";
   rc   =   sqlite3_exec(conn, sql, 0, 0, 0);
   if   (rc != SQLITE_OK)
   {   printf   ("Cannot access table, rc = %d,\n%s\n", rc, sqlite3_errmsg (conn));
      printf   ("sql = %s", sql);
      return   -2;
   }
   printf("db table (?)created\n");

   rc = sqlite3_exec(conn,
               "update people set phonenumber=\'5055559999\' where id=3",
               0, 0, 0);
   //printf ("1st update done with rc = %d\n", rc);

   rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(conn,
               "select lastname,firstname,phonenumber,id from people order by id",
               1000, &res, &tail);
   printf ("prepare statement executed\n");

   if (rc != SQLITE_OK) 
   {   puts("We did not get any data!");
      exit(0);
   }

   puts("==========================");

   while (sqlite3_step(res) == SQLITE_ROW) 
   {   printf("%s|", sqlite3_column_text(res, 0));
      printf("%s|", sqlite3_column_text(res, 1));
      printf("%s|", sqlite3_column_text(res, 2));
      printf("%u\n", sqlite3_column_int(res, 3));

      rec_count++;
   }

   puts("==========================");
   printf("We received %d records.\n", rec_count);

   sqlite3_finalize(res);

   sqlite3_close(conn);

   return 0;
}
```

if I comment out:
`printf ("1st update done with rc = %d\n", rc); // <<== THIS STATEMENT`
I get a segment fault.  Otherwise I appear to get a normal completion.
gcc -v --> 
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=gcc
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
    Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
    Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.7.2-5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --with-arch-32=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5) 

However, I also get a (less analyzed) segment fault on Debian testing.
Any suggestions?  (I note that a similar error was answered by "You need to allocate space for the sql string, but I'm using a literal, so that shouldn't apply.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` call fails because you lie about the string length:

```
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(conn,
           "select lastname,firstname,phonenumber,id from people order by id",
           1000, &res, &tail);
```

It appears to work if you include the `printf` call because the string literal will be placed in the same section as the string who's length you lie about, and whatever `sqlite3_prepare_v2` is doing just spills over the other string.

What you have here is effectively a buffer overrun.

Comment: Thanks.
       sql = "select lastname,firstname,phonenumber,id from people order by id";
       rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(conn, sql,
                   strlen(sql), &res, &tail);
seems to fix it.

Comment: From the documentation you can just not pass a length and let sqlite figure it out.